# AngularJS ng-show directive not working on scope function like it should

Tags: angularjs

What is wrong with this simple ng-show directive? It should be simple as I have to buttons hidden using ng-show and when a third button is clicked these two buttons will show So they are hidden until a button is clicked

javascript

```
$scope.addQuestion = function () {
        $('button#addQuestion').click(function(){
            $scope.addQuestion = true;
            console.log("clicked");
        })
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="program-edit-btns well">
<!--These two buttons are hidden until the third button is clicked-->
  <div class="btn-group pull-left" ng-show="addQuestion()">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-remove"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-remove"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> copy</button>
</div>

 <!--This button triggers the ng-show-->
 <button id="addQuestion" type="button" class="btn btn-remove pull-left">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> question
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to avoid using jquery handlers while using angular.. Here you are registering a click event every digest cycle... Also note that your function on the scope and the scope variable are of same name...

Answer (score 1):

You got a mix and match.. You just need this:-

No more jquery click event handler, just add a handler function, set the variable on the scope:-

```
$scope.addQuestion = function () {
      $scope.showQuestion = true;
}
```

and `ng-show="showQuestion"` on the section and `ng-click="addQuestion()"` on the trigger.

```
<div class="program-edit-btns well">
<!--These two buttons are hidden until the third button is clicked-->
  <div class="btn-group pull-left" ng-show="showQuestion">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-remove"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-remove"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> copy</button>
</div>

 <!--This button triggers the ng-show-->
 <button id="addQuestion" ng-click="addQuestion()" type="button" class="btn btn-remove pull-left">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> question
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @jmccommas You are welcome... Hope you got your issue resolved!!

Comment: @jmccommas Do you mind accepting the answer that helped you most?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the scope inside a Jquery function, you have to call the $apply method manually

```
$scope.addQuestion = function () {
        $('button#addQuestion').click(function(){
            $scope.addQuestion = true;
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log("clicked");
        })
    }
```

But I am pretty sure you don't need JQuery to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I have tried this but still is not showing the other two buttons

Comment: One more question, if I wanted to add a class on that click event would I add it like this: $scope.addQuestion = function (event) {
            $scope.showQuestion = true;
            $(event.target).addClass('disabled');
        }

Comment: @jmccommas You should just use angular to add class i.e use `ng-class` and bind it on some variable i.e `<button id="addQuestion" ng-class="{disabled:showQuestion}"` Similarly you could use `<button ng-disabled="showQuestion"`. If you really want to use event then you need to pass `$event` as argument from the view to the function handler